# Create a common xsd generated class to be used by other packages

Tags: xsd, jaxb, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am trying to use the same generated class but in separate packages.  So the structure should look something like this:

```
com.test.common
     -commonType.java
com.test.A
     -objectA.java
com.test.B
     -objectB.java
```

But i keep getting this:

```
com.test.common
     -commonType.java
com.test.A
     -objectA.java
     -commonType.java
com.test.B
     -objectB.java
     -commonType.java
```

My common.xsd looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0"
    targetNamespace="http://test.com/magic/common"
    xmlns="http://test.com/magic/common"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jaxb:version="2.0">

    <xs:complexType name="CommonType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

the objectA.xsd looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0"
    targetNamespace="http://test.com/magic/objectA"
    xmlns:common="http://test.com/magic/common"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jaxb:version="2.0">

    <xs:complexType name="ObjectA">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="size" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="commonA" type="common:CommonType" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

And objectB.xsd looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0"
    targetNamespace="http://test.com/magic/objectB"
    xmlns:common="http://test.com/magic/common"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jaxb:version="2.0">

    <xs:complexType name="ObjectB">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="version" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="commonB" type="common:CommonType" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

I have a common binding file common.xjb which looks like this:

```
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/common.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.test.common"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
```

And finally my maven job looks like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xequals</arg>
                </args>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                        <version>0.6.3</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
                <episode>true</episode>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <generateDirectory>src/main/java</generateDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>common</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generatePackage>com.test.common</generatePackage>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <includeSchema>xsd/common.xsd</includeSchema>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>login</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generatePackage>com.test.A</generatePackage>
                        <bindingIncludes>
                            <includeBinding>xjb/commons.xjb</includeBinding>
                        </bindingIncludes>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <includeSchema>xsd/objectA.xsd</includeSchema>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>alert</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generatePackage>com.test.B</generatePackage>
                        <bindingIncludes>
                            <includeBinding>xjb/commons.xjb</includeBinding>
                        </bindingIncludes>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <includeSchema>xsd/objectB.xsd</includeSchema>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a part in the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` documentation dedicated specifically to the [separate schema compilation](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Modular-Schema-Compilation). But you can also achieve your goal with usual XJC bindings.

- Do not use `generatePackage` in the plugin config, use `jaxb:package` in bindings, ex.:

  ```
  <jaxb:schemaBindings>
      <jaxb:package name="generatePackage"/>
  </jaxb:schemaBindings>
  ```
- Use `<jaxb:class ref="com.test.common.CommonType"/>` on `commonType` in `xjb/commons.xjb`.

SO Disclaimer: I'm the author of the `maven-jaxb2-plugin`.

Comment: @SarvarNishonboev Done.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `-episode` extension in the JAXB XJC to handle this use case:

**XJC call for common.xsd**

```
xjc -d out -episode common.episode common.xsd
```

**XJC call for objectA.xsd**

The episode file produced from the first step is really a JAXB external bindings file that contains links between schema types and existing classes.  This prevents XJC from regenerating these classes.

```
xjc -d out objectA.xsd -extension -b common.episode
```

**For a Detailed Example**

- [Can Castor handle class generation from multiple XSDs importing from a base XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986082/can-castor-handle-class-generation-from-multiple-xsds-importing-from-a-base-xsd)

Comment: I tried using that but i still result in the CommonType being generated both times

Comment: I had to add the necessary XML schema imports `<xs:import namespace="http://test.com/magic/common" schemaLocation="common.xsd"/>` but once I did I was able to use the command line XJC as described in my answer to only generate the classes from common.xsd once.

Comment: that's correct the command line works as expected but for some reason the maven plugin is not working even when i specify <episodeFile> <extenstion> <bindingInclude> configurations

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions using JAXB 3 and `maven-jaxb-plugin` version `3.1.0`.

## Solution 1, with several XJB files

You have to make 4 XJB files:

- `common.xjb` and `commonClasses.xjb` for the common types
- `objectA.xjb` for the types specific to `objectA.xsd`
- `objectB.xjb` for the types specific to `objectB.xsd`

`common.xjb` will put the common types into the `com.test.common` Java package:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bindings version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="http://test.com/magic/common">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.test.common"/>
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

`commonClasses.xjb` will instruct `objectA` and `objectB` to reuse the common types from the `com.test.common` Java package:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bindings version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="https://namespace1">
    <bindings scd="~tns:CommonType1">
      <class ref="com.test.common.CommonType1"/>
    </bindings>
    <bindings scd="~tns:CommonType2">
      <class ref="com.test.common.CommonType2"/>
    </bindings>
    <!-- ... -->
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Note that `maven-jaxb-plugin` can generate the `commonClasses.xjb` file for you, from execution on the `common.xsd`. Check out the `target/classes/META-INF/JAXB` directory for the generated episode files after the execution. Maybe you will even be able to specify the generated XJB episode file from the `target/` in the `pom.xml` file, but I have not tried that.

`objectA.xjb` will put the `objectA.xsd` specific types into `com.test.A`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bindings version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="http://test.com/magic/objectA">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.test.A"/>
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

`objectB.xjb` will put the `objectB.xsd` specific types into `com.test.B`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bindings version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="http://test.com/magic/objectB">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.test.B"/>
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

`pom.xml` content updated for the newer `maven-jaxb-plugin`:

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>

        <!-- Common configuration for all executions -->
        <configuration>
          <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
        </configuration>

        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>xjc-common</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>common.xsd</source>
              </sources>
              <xjbSources>
                <xjbSource>common.xjb</xjbSource>
              </xjbSources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

          <execution>
            <id>xjc-objectB</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>objectA.xsd</source>
              </sources>
              <xjbSources>
                <xjbSource>commonClasses.xjb</xjbSource>
                <xjbSource>objectA.xjb</xjbSource>
              </xjbSources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

          <execution>
            <id>xjc-objectB</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>objectB.xsd</source>
              </sources>
              <xjbSources>
                <xjbSource>commonClasses.xjb</xjbSource>
                <xjbSource>objectB.xjb</xjbSource>
              </xjbSources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

---

## Solution 2, with one merged XJB file

Given that you have `common`, `objectA` and `objectB` XML types residing in different XML namespaces, maybe you can merge `common.xjb`, `objectA.xjb` and `objectB.xjb` into 1 XJB file, avoid `common-classes.jxb` entirely, and run everything in 1 execution, but I haven't tried that.

You can try the following merged XJB file, let's call it `merged.xjb`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bindings version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="http://test.com/magic/common">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.test.common"/>
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="http://test.com/magic/objectA">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.test.A"/>
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="http://test.com/magic/objectB">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.test.B"/>
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

And the following `pom.xml` block:

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>

        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>xjc-merged</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>common.xsd</source>
                <source>objectA.xsd</source>
                <source>objectB.xsd</source>
              </sources>
              <xjbSources>
                <xjbSource>merged.xjb</xjbSource>
              </xjbSources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```