# JAXB how to resolve 'is already defined' error when two XSD's of same namespace declare the same element

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

So I have the following bindings.xjb to load a top level XSD that loads two child XSD's (both children have the same namespace).

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="TopLevel.xsd">
</jxb:bindings>
```

Now the two child XSD's (lets call them childA and childB) both declare the same simple type ('ResponseTypeCodeEnumeration').

So I get the error

```
SAXParseException: 'ResponseTypeCodeEnumeration' is already defined
```

Normally I'd use a bindings entry to resolve the conflict. I don't know how to specifically reference the element in one of the child xsd's or what I would set it to resolve this problem.

Note: I don't own either XSD, so I'm not technically allowed to change them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You describe a top level schema (parent) that is invalid since it pulls in the same scope two (child) XSDs that happen to define same simple type.

If that is the case, there is nothing you can do to fix the problem without fixing the XSDs.

If the parent schema is also provided to you, then push it back to the provider to fix it. Otherwise, if it's your own doing, you have no choice but to refactor the child XSDs to suit your scenario. An invalid (parent) XSD would be useless anyway (you won't be able to validate an XML, etc.)

If you have different parent XSDs, that pull from the same pool of "child" schemas, and where each parent XSD is valid, then you can use [JAXB episodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013963/create-a-common-xsd-generated-class-to-be-used-by-other-packages) to generate only one set of classes for the common schemas. The episode will be referenced every time you generate classes for a parent XSD.