# JAXB - Customizing a generated class name, but configuring for not generating it

Tags: web-services, xsd, wsdl, jaxb

I have multiple WSDL/XSD files and using JAXB I'm generating it's clients. But there are some common classes among them all, that I have in a separate project.

I'm able to customize the whole generation, informing custom names to client classes as needed. But for those common classes, I would like just to inform their names for reference, but not generate them, using the ones provided in another project, and included in the classpath.

Is that possible using JAXB customizations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer linked below demonstrates how to use a JAXB external bindings file to specify that a type in an XML schema corresponds to an existing Java class:

- [JAXB - Creating modules for reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869547/jaxb-creating-modules-for-reuse/5870671#5870671)

If the existing classes are also generated from an XML schema, then you may be interested in the `-episode` extension that enables the artifacts generated from an XML schema to be used by the artifacts generated by another schema that imports the first.

- [Can Castor handle class generation from multiple XSDs importing from a base XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986082/can-castor-handle-class-generation-from-multiple-xsds-importing-from-a-base-xsd/7986486#7986486)

Comment: The answer linked is very useful. Also the links included in there. Thanks!