# how to inherit objectfactory in jaxb

Tags: java, inheritance, jaxb, xsd

I would like to how to extend/inherit `Objectfactory`.The scenario is very simple.

suppose i have `xsd_A` which defines a complextype `address`. There is another `xsd_b` which imports `xsd_a` and references `address` or it create element of type `address`. i have few requirements

i would like the `objectfactory` of `xsd_b` to extend `xsd_a` and avoid redefining `createAddress()` .

how is it possible? i would like not to have `Address.java` in package `xsd_b`. i would like all classes in `xsd_b` to reference `Address.java` generated by `xsd_a`.

Note the class refers the `address` generted by `xsd_a`.

Comment: Do you actually mean `xsd_b` does an `<xs:import>` on `xsd_a`, or did you mean `<xs:include>`?  The difference is critical.

Comment: xsd b import xsd a and then does <element ref=xsda:address> .Now i dont want address to be created in java package b.but it should be imported in java class from package a.Episode is the  answer and it worked. :) thanks for asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reuse the classes generated from xsd_a when you generate classes from xsd_b (which imports xsd_a) is to use the episode file extension in XJC.  For a full example see my answer to a similar question.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7986486/383861

Comment: Thanks .It works.Sorry for my late response .But I am unable to use Typesafeenum in XSD as internal jaxb binding info.It complains of conflicting configuration.